# How to decompile an exe file compiled by py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe, decompiler

How to decompile an exe file compiled by py2exe?

just one exe file, didn'n have any zip file.

how to decompile to pyc or pyo file?

Comment: Why are you hoping to be able to do this?

Comment: There's very little you can do to reverse it without the `library` zip archive.

Comment: As far as I know an exe file is an encapsulation type because my Linux package manager opens them as such.

Comment: py2exe can bundle the library.zip into the .exe.  Assuming that is the case here (and that you're not simply missing the library.zip), then you can simply extract the files from the .exe (treat it as a zipfile) and you're left with .pyc files.  For decompiling pyc to py, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378127/pyc-to-py-files

Answer (score 24):

You can use [unpy2exe](https://github.com/matiasb/unpy2exe) to extract the .pyc and then use [pyREtic](https://github.com/MyNameIsMeerkat/pyREtic/blob/master/docs/HOWTO.md) to get the source code. I guess you can read the HOWTO and understand how to use these programs, but basically you go to the location of unpy2exe.py and run:

> unpy2exe.py [-h] [-o OUTPUT_DIR] [-p PYTHON_VERSION] filename

thene go to the location of REpdb.py and run:

> REpdb.py
>
> set_project [new project name]

Select the python version

> fs_um_decompile [location of pyc file]

The source should be in ...\Projects[new project name]\sourcecode\fs_um\

Comment: unpy2exe worked like a charm for me.  pyREtic, however, failed with a TypeError about a string being a list, which I failed to decode on the interwebs.  That tool looks like it's designed to undo obfuscation of bytecode.  For my problem, uncompyle6 was enough.  Linking to the source was the right thing to do but pip install worked for both uncompyle6 and unpy2exe.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach is to take the python byte code dump directly from memory, Immunity Inc published a paper about this subject with a toolkit that takes the bytecode from memory and decompile it to .py source code.
[pyREtic](http://www.immunityinc.com/resources-freesoftware.shtml)

Answer (score 9):

I have wrote a small tool in C++ which takes a py2exe generated executable and extracts the `PYTHONSCRIPT` and `Library.zip`. The `Library.zip` contains mostly pyc/pyo files, you can decompile them using any decompiler.

**Links :**

**Py2ExeDumper** : ***https://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exedumper/***

**Easy Python Decompiler** : **http://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/**

Answer (score 1):

Use script provided [here](http://code.google.com/p/py2exe-extract/). It requires the original py2exe Python module to be installed. Also you must ensure that you use the same Python version originaly used to produce the executable. Otherwise the script will produce invalid magic number for the .pyc.
Later you can use [uncompyle2](https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2) to restore the original .py source.