# Extracting from EXE

Tags: python, interpreter

Ok, i have a .exe file with python interpreter active. What would i put into the console to extract .pyc from the executable? Or is it a completely different way.

The problem i am having is trying to extract the pyc files. Since i don't know any script to put into the console i've tried multiple python application decompilers. None of them worked because of coding errors.

If anyone knows how to extract these pyc files via interpreter please say how.

Thank you,
Jacob

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287918/how-to-decompile-an-exe-file-compiled-by-py2exe