# Python 32 bit to 64 bit?

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm using a program designed in python from 2006... 2.4 to be exact. I keep running into memory errors with it and want to upgrade the thing to 64 bit; except that I have not touched python in almost 20 years. I have the library and the exe, and have determined the exe was created through py2exe. Is it possible to upgrade this to 2.7 64 bit without needing to rewrite the entire app ?

Comment: Only if you can get the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to decompile the code (see [How to decompile an exe file compiled by py2exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287918/how-to-decompile-an-exe-file-compiled-by-py2exe)), then recompile it with a current version of py2exe.

This is assuming you've lost the original source code--having that would make things easier.

Comment: The app was at v11 in its last publish. V10 had its source code publish, however was error ridden and missing many features of v11. Also, my memory is obviously fuzzy on python, the exe is only 26KB and the library is 4.7MB. I've opened the exe using 7zip and confirmed there is nothing compressed, it is 26KB. I've also compared files for the source code of v10 to the library of v11... and found many files with the same name, the only difference is the v11 files are pyo vs v10 source is py. Is it possible this person included the source in the library?